# How to add fields to the X-Cart checkout?

Tags: php, field, smarty, x-cart

So basically I would like to add a "How did you hear about us?" field to the checkout. Just with basic options such as "Google", "Newspaper", "Website" etc.. Is this do-able first of all, if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **General Settings -> User Profiles**
Then add your question under "**Add new field**" with select box option, hit Add/Update and check "**Customer at checkout**" box.